# How to make dynamic list transferring "unknown" id's work with static script

Tags: php, jquery

Note #1: `var id = $("#mysqlid").val();` is supposed to be the value from the hidden field from the **form** where the delete button has been pushed.

The `id` is **unknown**, since it is the `auto_increment id` from the ever changing database. To make it unique.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(document).on("click", "#delete", function(){

        var id = $("#mysqlid").val(); // Note #1

        $.ajax({
            type:"post",
            url:"http://www.mydomain.no/action.php",
            data:"id="+id+"&action=delete",
            success:function(data){
                showList(); 
                // showlist() returns an updated list of entries from the database after the selected row is deleted.
            }

        });
    });
});
</script> 

<table id="list">
    <theader>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td><td>Action</td>
        </tr>
    </theader>
    <tbody>
        <!-- Content from action.php start here -->
        <tr>
            <td>Test data</td>
            <td>
                <form>
                    <input type="hidden" id="mysqlid13" value="13">
                    <a href="#" id="delete">
                        <img style="cursor:pointer;" src="gfx/delete.png" alt="Delete">
                    </a>
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Test data 2</td>
            <td>
                <form>
                    <input type="hidden" id="mysqlid14" value="14">
                    <a href="#" id="delete">
                        <img style="cursor:pointer;" src="gfx/delete.png" alt="Delete">
                    </a>
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <!-- Content from action.php ends here -->
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I've removed all the excess code, as to not clutter the issue at hand.

I'm sure this is an easy fix for someone more advanced in javascript than me.

Comment: add a class name to the elements you wish to delete then you just need to select by the class and not some unknown id.

Comment: But the class name would have to be known and unique?

Comment: I don't understand you wanna delete the whole `tr` that contains the selected delete link? or get the id of the `input` beside the selected link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd prefer to do this in a bit better approach, like this

> **Note** it's invalid HTML to have duplicate ID in a document, please change it to class

```
<form>
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="14" />
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="delete" /> 
    <a href="#" class="delete">
        <img style="cursor:pointer;" src="gfx/delete.png" alt="Delete" />
    </a>
</form>


$(document).on("click", ".delete", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent default action
    var that = this;
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "http://www.mydomain.no/action.php",
        data: $(that).closest('form').serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            showList();
            // showlist() returns an updated list of entries from the database after the selected row is deleted.
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: @Øyvind Note this still has multiple elements with the same id (links with id delete) on the same page, which is not valid html and many not work as expected in some browsers. Simply change the id to a class and this (or one of the answers on this page) will work fine (they all just have slightly different ways of identifying the correct input)

Comment: @user574632 good catch, I didn't notice that. Updating the answer.

Answer (score 1):

As per my previous suggestion, you can assign a common class name to the elements that will need to be grabbed and passed back to the server. The class name wouldn't have to be unique just known. If you give all the elements you wish to perform this action on the same class name you can select those elements, get their values, and pass them back in your ajax call.
Given html:

```
<form>
   <input type="hidden" id="mysqlid13" class='deleteMe' value="13">
   <a href="#" id="delete">
        <img style="cursor:pointer;" src="gfx/delete.png" alt="Delete">
   </a>
</form>
```

Your js could become:

```
$(document).on("click", "#delete", function(){
    var id = $(this).closest("form").find(".deleteMe").val();
    /*make your ajax call or whatever*/
});
```

Now if you only have that one hidden input element per form element you could even simplify it and not even use an identifier and select by type:

```
 $(document).on("click", "#delete", function(){
     var id = $(this).closest("form").find("input[type='hidden']").val();
    /*make your ajax call or whatever*/
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the direct way of getting the data I want, these techniques will be saved for later usage :)

Answer (score 0):

set data format , it may not pass like query string and complete url may not work cause of CORS

```
   $.ajax({
      type:"post",
      url:"/action.php",
      data:{"id":id,"action":"delete"},
      success:function(data){
      showList(); 
      }
```

Comment: It's not a problem with getting the id through to the php script. The problem is fetching the value of a "unknown" field. I need a way to select an exact field among 30.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to change you links to use a class, not an id, as ids **must** be unique. So you html becomes

```
<a href="#" class="delete">...
```

Then your js becomes

```
$(document).on("click", ".delete", function(){
    var id = $(this).prev("input").val();
    ...
}
```